# Eliminar caracteres específicos de una columna que contiene varios datos

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, str-replace, replace

Buen día, cuento con un df:

```
count                       50
unique                      50
top       desde 5.22 hasta 6.9
freq                         1
Name: espesor_pared, dtype: object
```

Estoy intentando quitar el "desde" para después hacer un split con "hasta", sacar el promedio y pasarlo a float, he intentado con replace:

```
df["espesor_pared"].replace({"desde":""}, inplace = True)
```

, sin embargo no ha funcionado, sigue la misma salida original.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para reemplazar `sub-strings` con [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) se necesita utilizar el argumento `regex`

```
df['espesor_pared'] = df['espesor_pared'].replace({'desde':''}, regex = True)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
        espesor_pared
count   50
unique  50
top     5.22 hasta 6.9
freq    1
```

Si tu objetivo es obtener únicamente los valores de 5.22 y 6.9 podrías reemplazar la palabra "hasta" en la misma línea de código

```
df['espesor_pared'] = df['espesor_pared'].replace({'desde':'', 'hasta':''}, regex = True)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
        espesor_pared
count   50
unique  50
top     5.22 6.9
freq    1
```

Y luego puedes hace el `split()` que mencionas en tu pregunta

Comment: Disculpa responder hasta ahora, muchas gracias, si funciono a la perfección

Comment: @DavidEstebanGarciaVeloza, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)